# Wordpress Select Template for Each Page on Activation

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, multisite

So, I have wordpress multisite. I want my users to be able to activate a new theme, and still have their content in place. The problem I am having is, everytime a new theme is activated, each page's template selection is updated to the 'default' template. I would like for example, the Home Page to keep the home-page.php template etc... I have tried naming the templates in all the themes the same.. but that did not work.

Am i clear? or do I need to explain more? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly take backup of all your WordPress data in .xml file 
   situated at example.com/wp-admin->Tools->Export
2. you also customize your new theme in custom tab, there you can access all the previous data from older theme

Comment: I want users to be able to switch between themes and still have 'Home page' template selected in the home page..